# Trying to pass data between two view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, master-detail, ibaction

I have a simple master-detail application that I am trying to pass data between one view controller to the next. I have one view controller that is presented as a modal view controller where the user selects an option from a `UIPickerView`, and depending on which row they select, the string gets set. However, when the view controller is `dismissed`, the string is null. When the user selects the login button on the modal view controller, it posts a notification for the master view controller to initiate a method using the string that was set by the `UIPickerView` however it keeps failing because the string is null. I have set parserURL as properties in each view controllers as well as ivars.

Here is the code that sets the string in the modal view controller:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    MasterViewController *master = [[MasterViewController alloc] init];

    if (row == 0) {
        [self.dropdownButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dropdown"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    if (row == 1) {
        [self.dropdownButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hbm"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [master setParserURL:@"http://98.246.50.81/firecom/xml/HBM.xml"];
        NSLog(@"URL = %@", master.parserURL);
    }
    if (row == 2) {
        [self.dropdownButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hwh"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [master setParserURL:@"http://98.246.50.81/firecom/xml/HWH.xml"];
    }
}
```

Login button IBAction:

```
-(IBAction)loginButton:(id)sender {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"login" object: nil];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not setting the string on your Master Instance but on an other instance that you just initialized for the occasion.

---

There is many ways that you can achieve that. Depending on the over all Architecture of your application.
The simplest, but not a very good way, would be to do this when you create your detail View Controller in your master
`DetailVC *dVC = [[DetailVC alloc] initWithNib:@"DetailVC" bundle:nil];

dVC.masterReference = self;`

then in your detail view controller you could refer directly to it like this : `self.masterRefence` and that would point to your `original` master view controller.

Comment: How would I set it on my Master Instance?

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the .h file to the page of coding?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to pass data between the view controllers is via Core Data. you should do your research on how this functionality works in ios, and it will help you in the long run.